# Converting to Ionic 4, but old Ionic 3 pages appear on second run

Tags: ionic4

I am converting an existing Ionic 3 app to Ionic 4. The first time I run the app on an Android emulator, I get the new Ionic 4 app. The *second time* I run the same app, I get the Ionic 3 app!

I did the conversion by starting with a new Ionic 4 starter project, generating new pages etc and then migrating the content into the new pages from the Ionic 3 app.

I build the new app with `ionic cordova build android` and it generates an APK: `platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`

I install the APK on an emulator with `adb install -r platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`

Then, as I described, the first time the app runs, it shows the new Ionic 4 app. I know it's the new app because I've added "Ionic 4" to the top nav toolbar. Then if I dismiss the app and run it again, I get the old Ionic 3 app come up instead. It's not even the current version of the Ionic 3 app - it's some older version of the app. I don't know where it's getting this old source from.

If I uninstall the app and re-install it, I again get the new Ionic 4 app one time only before it goes back to the Ionic 3 app.

I've tried:

- Creating a brand new emulator, so the Ionic 3 app has never been installed on it. No change.
- Removing and re-adding the android platform. No change.
- Checked that the pages are definitely only in my project once (so I don't have version 3 and 4 pages together).
- Tried debug and release builds. No change.

Any thoughts? I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ionic 4 Globally

> [ionicframework](https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/cli)

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. The Ionic 4 app now includes the [cordova-plugin-ionic](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic) plugin, which will automatically attempt to upgrade the app at runtime from the Ionic Pro repository. This upgrade runs in the background by default when you launch the app. We had an Ionic 3 version of the app in the Ionic Pro repository, with the same APP_ID as the Ionic 4 app. So when our Ionic 4 app ran, it silently "upgraded" itself to the Ionic 3 version of the app. Then the next launch of the app would run the Ionic 3 version of the app.